# SQL - How to group by and take first row of columns?

Tags: sql-server, erp

I have the following SQL query

```
select SI.C_NUMBER as 'Invoice Number'
,SI.C_DATE as 'Date'
, CU.C_NAME as 'Customer'
, SI.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE as 'Customer Order Number'
, SIL.C_NETAMOUNT as 'Items Net'
,MAN.C_NAME as 'Manufacturer'
from T_SALESINVOICE as SI WITH(NOLOCK)
inner join T_SALESINVOICE_LINE as SIL WITH(NOLOCK) on SIL.C__OWNER_ = SI.C_ID
inner join T_PRODUCT as PR WITH(NOLOCK) on PR.C_ID = SIL.C_PRODUCT
inner join T_MANUFACTURER as MAN WITH(NOLOCK) on MAN.C_ID = PR.C_MANUFACTURER
inner join T_CUSTOMER as CU WITH(NOLOCK) on CU.C_ID = SI.C_CUSTOMER
where CU.C_NAME = 'TEST CUSTOMER'
```

Which works perfectly, but I now need to Group by Invoice number, while taking the first result of Manufacturer, the reason for this is we have multiple item lines per invoice. Additionally, I need the Items Net to be the total of the 3 lines, while Manufacturer is only the first row.

So far I've tried;

```
select SI.C_NUMBER as 'Invoice Number'
,SI.C_DATE as 'Date'
, CU.C_NAME as 'Customer'
, SI.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE as 'Customer Order Number'
, SUM(SIL.C_NETAMOUNT) as 'Items Net'
,MAN.C_NAME as 'Manufacturer'
from (
select SI.C_NUMBER
, SI.C_DATE
, CU.C_NAME
, SI.C_ALTERNATEREFERENCE
, SUM(SIL.C_NETAMOUNT)
, MAN.C_NAME
,row_number() over(partition by SI.C_NUMBER order by SI.C_DATE desc) as roworder
from T_SALESINVOICE as SI WITH(NOLOCK)
inner join T_SALESINVOICE_LINE as SIL WITH(NOLOCK) on SIL.C__OWNER_ = SI.C_ID
inner join T_PRODUCT as PR WITH(NOLOCK) on PR.C_ID = SIL.C_PRODUCT
inner join T_MANUFACTURER as MAN WITH(NOLOCK) on MAN.C_ID = PR.C_MANUFACTURER
inner join T_CUSTOMER as CU WITH(NOLOCK) on CU.C_ID = SI.C_CUSTOMER
) temp
where roworder = 1
and CU.C_NAME = 'TEST CUSTOMER'
```

But unfortunately gee the error "Column 'T_SALESINVOICE.C_NUMBER' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function of the GROUP BY clause."
I know almost nothing of SQL, started trying to mess with this today.

Edit:
Example of current result;

| Invoice Number | Customer | Order Number | Items Net | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Test | PO999 | 659.00 | Dell |
| 1234 | Test | PO999 | 123.00 | HP |
| 1235 | Test | PO998 | 451.00 | Dell |
| 1236 | Test | PO997 | 871.00 | Lenovo |
| 1236 | Test | PO997 | 253.00 | Dell |

Desired result;

| Invoice Number | Customer | Order Number | Items Net | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Test | PO999 | 782.00 | Dell |
| 1235 | Test | PO998 | 451.00 | Dell |
| 1236 | Test | PO997 | 1124.00 | Lenovo |

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: Is there a reason you're spamming the `NOLOCK` hint? Do you understand what it does? Why not change the isolation level?

Comment: @Larnu The reason is I have no idea what I am doing honestly! This is inside an ERP system and other SQL queries in there did the same thing, so I just copied them.

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if you show us sample data and your expected outcome, please show this in text form not in an image

Comment: Then I really do suggest unlearning that awful habit; the spamming of `NOLOCK` is a great route to getting wrong and unreliable data.

Comment: The error, on the other hand, is telling you the problem. You have an aggregate function (`SUM`) but no `GROUP BY`; this means that *every column* needs to be aggregated or a literal value. You likely need to add the correct `GROUP BY` to your query, or it perhaps you shouldn't be aggregating (I suspect this is the actual case).